# linux alias with part of path

Tags: linux, bash, alias

Lately I have been getting familiar with aliases in the linux shell. I find them particularly useful for replacing hdfs dfs commands like this:

```
alias hls="hdfs dfs -ls"
```

This alias can be used like

```
hls /my/directory/
```

which will list the contents in that folder on the hadoop file system.

I would like to add another hdfs dfs -ls alias that contains a root directory, something along the lines of:

```
alias hlsr="hdfs dfs -ls /my/root/directory/"
```

I would then want to use this command as follows:

```
hlsr rest/of/path
```

which would then result in listing the contents of the path /my/root/directory/rest/of/path.

The problem is combining the alias, that ends with a root path, with a string which represents the rest of that path.

Does anyone know how to do this? Would I have to write a function or could it be done with aliases as well?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function in a file to be sourced. Let's call a file with name `myfunctions.sh`

```
hls () 
{ 
    hdfs dfs -ls "$1";
}
```

The argument `$1` is your first parameter and then you have to source the file with `source myfunctions.sh` or `. myfunctions.sh`.

Comment: I'd also quote the variable for paths containing whitespace: `hdfs dfs -ls "$1"`.

Comment: Upvoted in spite of the quoting issue -- always prefer functions over aliases.

Comment: He asked for `hlsr() { hdfs dfs -ls /my/root/directory/"$1"; }`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately none of these options work. I'm trying to make the root directory extendable by whatever path I want to list from there on. i.e. 

    hlsr further/folder/path

should list the contents of /my/root/directory/further/folder/path.
When I specify the function as @ceving proposed it will first list /my/root/directory/ and subsequently say further/folder/path/: no such file or directory.

I don't know if it matters but I am specifying all this in my .bash_profile.

Thanks, Joost

Comment: `.profile` will be run every time you login, `.bashrc` on the other hand will be runned everytime you open a new terminal.Any of the options should work. You can take a look to a bash functions tutorial such as [this one](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functions.php). Good luck!